# How can I create functional internal links when converting an Excel document to a PDF? Link to Place in this document

Tags: excel, pdf-generation, vba6

I'm seeking guidance on how to create and maintain functional **internal links** when converting an Excel document to a PDF. These internal links are crucial for **navigation within the document.**

I've encountered challenges while attempting to create and preserve functional internal links when converting an Excel document to a PDF. Despite trying various methods, such as

1. Save as PDF
2. Export PDF/XPS
3. Print to PDF
4. And even tried converting excel to pdf online website

none of them have successfully retained the link locations within the PDF.

Given these challenges, I'm seeking a definitive solution. Could you please offer any alternative methods to ensure that internal links are carried over seamlessly to the PDF format from Excel?

I am using Excel standard 2021 version

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I am trying the best possibilites out of it. But my office laptop is very limited licence and pplication. I could not afford for  Adobe Editor, I do have Foxit and Xchange editor, not working.

Comment: After converting excel to pdf, any Editor has Add link or Bookmark option. I've created desired links and exact place where to go, fixed zoom level and even highlighted the mouseover, saved kept one pdf as a master copy and select all link boxes - copy - opened another pdf report with similar TOC content, then paste it, all the properties what i fixed had stick to it and saved. Now the links works across all the PDF. Solved!. 
As you suggest I used Xchange Editor to this task. Great! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

There are many suggestions as to work around this issue.

Here is by far the simplest, just link to the known file output, so on the assumption page 2 will be sheet 2 as I will be exporting all sheets and each will only be one page. **However this locks the links to a relative fixed filename and location.**, thus of some limited use.

[image]

The correct way is to use a full copy of Acrobat plugin for Office which has an Adobe Save as PDF function to pre-empt which reference may later be which page!
Alternatives are use HTML export, MS Word or Libre/open office but usually they cause other problems in styling.

For finer addresses (within a page level) then **it is best to use an external editor** and many free PDF editors can add finer page hyperlinks, using many variable methods.

For navigating bulk addresses, say more than  a dozen, then **"Outline / Bookmarks" are probably better**, and again there are many free PDF bookmark via command line editors.